# How Can I delete all pointers to the same address? C++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, smart-pointers

I'm trying to realize a smart pointer by myself.  I know that I can use smart pointers instead of this but I'm trying to do this only for understanding smart pointers structure.

Тhe problem is the following when my smart pointer has been starting to call the destructor, this is checking if my pointer is not `nullptr` then if it is true this will delete ptr.

After this when the destructor has been calling again for CastS I'm getting an exception because the destructor is trying to delete an already deleted element and my if statement for the second time isn't working (as I was expecting) because after the deletion of an element the address is changing and the pointer isn't null anymore.

How Can I improve this code and how can I not delete twice already deleted pointer?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename T>
class Smart_Pointer
{
private:
    T* ptr;
public:
    Smart_Pointer(T* ptr);
    ~Smart_Pointer();
    T& operator*();
};
template<typename T>
Smart_Pointer<T>::Smart_Pointer(T* ptr)
{
    this->ptr = ptr;
}

template<typename T>
Smart_Pointer<T>::~Smart_Pointer()
{
    if (ptr != nullptr)
    {
        delete ptr;
        ptr = nullptr;
        
    }

}

template<typename T>
T& Smart_Pointer<T>::operator*()
{
    return *ptr;
}

int main()
{
    Smart_Pointer<int> castS(new int(10));
    Smart_Pointer<int> castS2 = castS;
}
```

Comment: This is not how smart pointers work.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `delete ptr;` word just fine if `ptr` is a null pointer; there's no need for `if (ptr != nullptr)`. And setting `ptr = nullptr;` after the delete is pointless, because the object is being destroyed, and `ptr` will no longer exist.

Comment: `Smart_Pointer(Smart_Pointer const&) = delete;` because the compiler generated copy constructor won't work.  And `Smart_Pointer& operator=(Smart_Pointer const&) = delete;` for the assignment operator, for the same reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Smart Pointer is an umbrella term. For the std library it describes `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`.

If you want to implement a unique ptr you need to ensure that only one
unique ptr owns the raw pointer, so you need to delete the **copy constructor** and **copy assignment operator**. To be able to transfer ownership between your unique pointers you have to provide **move constructor** and **move assignment operator** in a way that the ownership is transferred.

If you want to implement a shared ptr you need to implement reference counting.

> How Can I delete all pointers to the same address? C++

That's something you don't want to do, you want to keep the managed object alive as long as there is at least one shared pointer owning that managed object.

[The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three):

> **Rule of three**: If a class requires a user-defined destructor, a user-defined copy constructor, or a user-defined copy assignment operator, it almost certainly requires all three.
>
> **Rule of five**: Because the presence of a user-defined destructor, copy-constructor, or copy-assignment operator prevents implicit definition of the move constructor and the move assignment operator, any class for which move semantics are desirable, has to declare all five special member functions:

Answer (score 1):

> How Can I delete all pointers to the same address? C++

You probably cannot do that reliably and automatically. Be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem), and read more about [*programming in C++*](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html), then see this [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Understand that pointers are organizing your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) as some [directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) which evolves during the execution of your program.

Maybe you want to *clear* all pointers to the same address.

### Then, read more about [Garbage Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)).

For example, read the [GC handbook](https://gchandbook.org/).

Consider using some static analysis tool on your C++ source code, e.g. the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

Consider also *generating* some your C++ code (like [SWIG](https://swig.org/) or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) does). You might code your generator of C++ code (e.g. using [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html), or your own generator of C++ files) to ease the management of your pointers.

Read also [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (some draft C++ standard) and the documentation of your C++ compiler (perhaps [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)).

Be aware that [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) has drawbacks (e.g. it is not multi-thread friendly).

Study for inspiration the source code of *existing* C++ open source programs (e.g. on [github](https://github.com/)), such as [Fish](https://fishshell.com/), [Qt](https://qt.io/), [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/), [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/). Consider contributing to one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to emulate the behaviour of unique_ptr, this is solved by simply not allowing copy. If you delete the copy constructor, no two smart pointers can be pointing to the same address at the same time. You simply write:

```
SmartPtr(const SmartPtr&) = delete;
```

However, if you do this you might want a way to transfer ownership, so it would be nice to implement a move constructor:

```
SmartPtr(SmartPtr&& other) {
    ptr = std::exchange(other.ptr, nullptr);
}
```

Or something like that. If you really want to allow two smart pointers to point to the same address, you need a way to decide which one is going to delete the ptr, usually the last one that goes out of scope. The way this is done in the standard (eg. In shared_ptr) is by defining a shared structure between all instances of the class, but that's probably way out of the scope of this answer..

Comment: I fixed it. It is not wrong however, just different from the standard

Comment: What do you mean by "different from the standard"? It's UB because you read an uninitialized variable, and `delete` should crash unless the pointer happens to be null.

Comment: I see, you are right. I was thinking move assignment.

Answer (score 0):

> How Can I delete all pointers to the same address?

First problem is that you don't know how *many* points to the same address.

This can be solved in many ways.

1. Using a control block (like std::shared_ptr) all smart pointers point to a control block that points to the real object and has a counter.
2. Using an intrusive counter in the pointer to object, either inherit it or the object must be inherited by the counter.
3. Using an external free counter.
4. Analyse all memory to see if anything points too that address (Garbage collection, GC).

The counter should be atomic if you intent to do multi-threading.

Implementing an external free counter has the huge advantage that you don't have the indirection of 1. and don't have the intrusiveness of 2 nor the complexity of GC.

Untested code

```cpp
std::unordered_map<void *, std::atomic_int> extro_count;
```

You then need to implement the rule of 3 or rule of 5 depending on how advanced you want to make it.

```cpp
template<typename T>
Smart_Pointer<T>::~Smart_Pointer() {
  if (ptr != nullptr) {
    if (--extro_count[ptr] == 0) {
      extro_count.erase(ptr);
      delete ptr;
      ptr = nullptr;
  }
}
```

I leave the implementation of the others to the OP.

This is still very unsafe in threaded code unless your careful.